# Prove $\forall x\in S:f(x)\leq g(x)\implies\text{supp}(f)\subseteq\text{supp}(g)$

Tags: functions

Let $f,g:S\to\Bbb R_{\geq0}$ where $\Bbb R_{\geq0}$ is the set of non-negative reals and $S$ is some set. I need to prove wether

$$\forall x\in S:f(x)\leq g(x)\implies\text{supp}(f)\subseteq\text{supp}(g)$$

holds where $\text{supp}(f)=\{x\in S\mid f(x)\neq 0\}$.

I feel like this is true, because intuitively a function $f$ that is less than another one $g$ at every point, $f$ can only have more zeros, so its support cannot contain more points than of $g$. The problem is that I cannot come up with a formal proof. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It may be somewhat easier to show that $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \setminus supp(g) \subseteq \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \setminus supp(f)$, which is equivalent.

Comment: Do you see that $f(x) \ne 0 \implies g(x) \ne 0$?

Comment: Actually, never mind, just think about elements. Suppose that $x \in supp(f)$, so that $f(x) \neq 0$. Then necessarily $f(x) > 0$. Can $g(x) = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in \text{supp}(f)$.  Then $f(x) > 0$ since the codomain of $f$ is the set of nonnegative real numbers.  The condition $f \le g$ on their domain $S$ implies that $g(x) \ge f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in S$., so $x \in \text{supp}(g)$.